# Cancel a closed pull request [GitHub]

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I  closing my pull request accidentally !!

So my pull request is closed state right now .how I can open this pull request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a reopen button on the button of your pull request

[image]

Click on it to re-open it.

---

If for some reason you still cant re-open it you can always push your changes again to github and open a new pull request.

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting your pull request, a button labeled "submit and re-open" should appear on comment form allowing you to reopening it.

Comment: But I lost all commit !!